# my clock doesnt work

Tags: kernel, compiling, time

My RTC clock doesn't work, on a particularly old piece of hardware, with equally old software. this messes with various processes like /proc/stat and ps, but it also throws errors ever time I try to update anything or build source packages. I'm currently trying to patch the kernel, and update the OS.

Messages include things like:

```
tar: kernel/lib/modules/3.14.28-g6327cdab/build/virt/kvm/vfio.c:
 time stamp 2022-12-06 23:30:58 is 63926203.378766698 s in the future
```

is this something that will prevent me from installing the kernel?
do i need to concern myself with this?

current kernel is 2.6.35.

trying to sync the clock:

```
#hwclock --debug
hwclock from util-linux 2.20.1
hwclock: Open of /dev/rtc failed: No such file or directory
No usable clock interface found.
hwclock: Cannot access the Hardware Clock via any known method.
```

Comment: Have you replace the battery?

Comment: I have, but linux kernel 2.6 doesn't have a device tree, ...and theres issues which is why Im trying to patch the kernel.

Comment: the kernel config will enable platform drivers which should include your RTC - look for it in the boot messages, and if there, set the date/time using `hwclock`. to answer your specific questions ... 1. it might; 2. maybe - try setting the date manually before doing anything

Comment: `/dev/rtc` might need to be a symbolic link to `/dev/rtc0` ... unless there are no `rtc` device files in `/dev` at all, in which case either `udev` is not creating them automatically, or the platform driver for your RTC is not configured in the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I updated my kernel to 3.14, which has a device tree, and now I can use hwclock to turn on my clock.